# Sqoop error while importing data from sql server to HDFS

Tags: sql-server, hadoop, sqoop

Getting below error while importing data from sql server to HDFS using sqoop:

```
cloudera@cloudera-vm:/lib$ sqoop list-databases --connect
```

> jdbc:sqlserver://192.168.127.1:6978 --username sa --password sa
>   16/01/17 10:35:32 WARN tool.BaseSqoopTool: Setting your password on
>   the command-line is insecure. Consider using -P instead. 16/01/17
>   10:35:32 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Got error creating database
>   manager: java.io.IOException: No manager for connect string:
>   jdbc:sqlserver://192.168.127.1:6978

Can anyone help me to solve this issue please?

Comment: What part of the error message are you not understanding?

Comment: Reformatted the code (no spaces at the beginning) + adapted error message by using "quoting"

Answer (score 0):

Based on sqoop documentation list-databases command only works against MySQL, oracle and HSQLDB databases. It doesn't work with ms sql server.
If you are verifying connection with my SQL Server, use other commands

https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.0-incubating/SqoopUserGuide.html#id1772839